# call Javascript function Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two javascript functions. 1) `InitializeGoogleMap` and  2) `GetPlaces`

the first loads the map when the page loads and the second function loads markers based on values from the db exposed using eval on a button event click.

both functions work the problem is that the `GetPlaces` function **loads the map again** to load the markers instead i want the `GetPlaces` function to use the same map created by `InitializeGoogleMap`

script:

```
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

      function InitializeGoogleMap() {

          try {
              DirectionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
              var LatitudeLongitude = new google.maps.LatLng(19.1969813, 72.9962491);
              var GoogleMapOptions =
                {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: LatitudeLongitude,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
              var map = new google.maps.Map($("#me")[0], GoogleMapOptions);

              DirectionsDisplay.setMap(map);
              DirectionsDisplay.setPanel($("#DivDirectionRouteStatus")[0]);



          }
          catch (E) {
              alert(E.message);
          }



      }




function GetPlaces() {

        try{


            var markers = 
                [<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                        {
                                            "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
                                            "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                                            "lng": '<%# Eval("Longatude") %>',
                                            "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                                        }
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <SeparatorTemplate>
                                ,
                            </SeparatorTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
            ];

            DirectionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();


            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

             var map = new google.maps.Map($("#me")[0], mapOptions);

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title
                });
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }


        }
        catch (E)
        {
            alert(E.message);
        }

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why the functions are in separate `<script>` blocks..? you can simply put them in same block, which in my opinion will be more readable...

Comment: Sorry they are in the same block just error pasting

Comment: You seems to be using different set of options in those functions. Do you just want to change the zoom and center in the second function..? or do you actually want to create a new map and keep the reference to it in the same variable..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your `map` variable global. Do not redeclare it in the `GetPlaces()` method For example...

```
var map;

function InitializeGoogleMap() {

      ...

      map = new google.maps.Map($("#me")[0], GoogleMapOptions);

      ...

}

function GetPlaces() {

    ...
        var markers = 
            [<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                    {
                                        "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
                                        "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                                        "lng": '<%# Eval("Longatude") %>',
                                        "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                                    }
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <SeparatorTemplate>
                            ,
                        </SeparatorTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
        ];

        DirectionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable `map` outside the functions,  and remove `var` keyword from the functions.

```
var map; // global
function InitializeGoogleMap() {
try {
          DirectionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
          var LatitudeLongitude = new google.maps.LatLng(19.1969813, 72.9962491);
          var GoogleMapOptions =
            {
                zoom: 10,
                center: LatitudeLongitude,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
          map = new google.maps.Map($("#me")[0], GoogleMapOptions); 

          DirectionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          DirectionsDisplay.setPanel($("#DivDirectionRouteStatus")[0]);
      }
      catch (E) {
          alert(E.message);
      }
  }
function GetPlaces() {
    try{
        var markers = 
            [<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                    {
                                        "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
                                        "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                                        "lng": '<%# Eval("Longatude") %>',
                                        "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                                    }
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <SeparatorTemplate>
                            ,
                        </SeparatorTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
        ];
        DirectionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
    catch (E)
    {
        alert(E.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have edited you code. Try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
var GoogleMapOptions =
                {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: LatitudeLongitude,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
var map = new google.maps.Map($("#me")[0], GoogleMapOptions);
      function InitializeGoogleMap() {

          try {
              DirectionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
              var LatitudeLongitude = new google.maps.LatLng(19.1969813, 72.9962491);
              /*var GoogleMapOptions =
                {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: LatitudeLongitude,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };*/
                //commented below
              //var map = new google.maps.Map($("#me")[0], GoogleMapOptions);

              DirectionsDisplay.setMap(map);
              DirectionsDisplay.setPanel($("#DivDirectionRouteStatus")[0]);



          }
          catch (E) {
              alert(E.message);
          }



      }




function GetPlaces() {

        try{


            var markers = 
                [<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                        {
                                            "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
                                            "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                                            "lng": '<%# Eval("Longatude") %>',
                                            "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                                        }
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <SeparatorTemplate>
                                ,
                            </SeparatorTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
            ];

            DirectionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();


            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            //commented below line
            // var map = new google.maps.Map($("#me")[0], mapOptions);

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title
                });
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }


        }
        catch (E)
        {
            alert(E.message);
        }

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This will not work. `GoogleMapsOptions` is declared inside the init function.

Comment: Why ? please state the reason !